# C++, pass two parameter packs to constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, mixins

I have the following problem. I have a class ([mixin](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/12/12/mixin-classes-yang-crtp/)), that has two template bases.

```
template <typename T>
class Id
{
    using result = T;
};

template <typename Printer1, typename Printer2>
class SeveralPrinters : public Printer1, public Printer2
{
    template <typename... Args1, typename... Args2>
    SeveralPrinters(dummy, helper<Args1...>, helper<Args2...>,
                    typename Id<Args1>::result... args1,
                    typename Id<Args2>::result... args2)
        : Printer1(std::forward<Args1>(args1)..., std::forward<Args2>(args2)...)
    {}
public:
    template <typename... Args, typename = 
std::enable_if_t<!contains<dummy, Args...>::result>>
    SeveralPrinters(Args&&... args)
        : SeveralPrinters(dummy(), typename Printer1::ArgsCtor(), 
typename Printer2::ArgsCtor(), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {
    }
};
```

All names of classes are fictitious. So, imagine its first base accepts `int` as constructor argument and second base accepts `double`. What I want to do is to be able to call constructor of `SeveralPrinters` like `SeveralPrinters(1, 2.)`. The problem here, is that `Args1` and `Args2` are deduced not from `helper` structure, but from args, passed after helper structure. As you can see, I tried to wrap template arguments into `Id` structure, and that didn't help. I know, it is called smth like **Non-deduced contexts**, but I couldn't manage to make it work. Can anyone help with it (if it possible), and maybe explain a little bit more on this topic (why it doesn't work now).
Example of base classes:

```
class BasicPrinter1
{
public:
    BasicPrinter1(int)
    {}
    void f()
    {
    }
    using ArgsCtor = helper<int>;
};

class BasicPrinter2
{
public:
    BasicPrinter2(int*)
    {}
    void g()
    {
    }
    using ArgsCtor = helper<int*>;
};
```

Comment: You cannot deduce two or more parameter packs from a single parameter list. End of story. You have to choose a different calling sequence. Perhaps a pair of tuples.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik OP is using a `helper` struct to deduce them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work mainly because the alias `result` in `Id` is *private* (default accessibility for classes), and so not accessible from the private constructor of `SeveralPrinters`, leading to a substitution failure (`typename Id<Args1>::result`) with no other viable candidate constructor to call. There were also a couple of typos in your code.

```
template <typename T>
struct Id
{
    using result = T;
};

template <typename Printer1, typename Printer2>
class SeveralPrinters : public Printer1, public Printer2
{
    template <typename... Args1, typename... Args2>
    SeveralPrinters(dummy, helper<Args1...>, helper<Args2...>
                  , typename Id<Args1>::result... args1
                  , typename Id<Args2>::result... args2)
        : Printer1(std::forward<Args1>(args1)...)
        , Printer2(std::forward<Args2>(args2)...)
    {}

public:    
    template <typename... Args>
    SeveralPrinters(Args&&... args)
        : SeveralPrinters(dummy{}
                        , typename Printer1::ArgsCtor{}
                        , typename Printer2::ArgsCtor{}
                        , std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cfc0863b051d768)

---

In order to perfectly-forward the arguments to base classes, you should instead declare the number of parameters (`ArgsCount`) and use the below implementation:

```
template <typename Printer1, typename Printer2>
class SeveralPrinters : public Printer1, public Printer2
{
    template <std::size_t... Is
            , std::size_t... Js
            , typename... Args>
    SeveralPrinters(std::index_sequence<Is...>
                  , std::index_sequence<Js...>
                  , std::tuple<Args...>&& t)
        : Printer1(std::get<Is>(std::move(t))...)
        , Printer2(std::get<sizeof...(Is) + Js>(std::move(t))...)
    {}

public:
    SeveralPrinters() = default;
    SeveralPrinters(const SeveralPrinters&) = default;
    SeveralPrinters(SeveralPrinters& rhs)
        : SeveralPrinters(static_cast<const SeveralPrinters&>(rhs))
    {}

    template <typename... Args>
    SeveralPrinters(Args&&... args)
        : SeveralPrinters(std::make_index_sequence<Printer1::ArgsCount>{}
                        , std::make_index_sequence<Printer2::ArgsCount>{}
                        , std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {}
};

struct BasicPrinter1
{
    BasicPrinter1(int) {}
    static constexpr ArgsCount = 1;
};

struct BasicPrinter2
{
    BasicPrinter2(int*, char&) {}
    static constexpr ArgsCount = 2;
};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/716aa6954bc6a913)

Also notice how I'm protecting the copy-constructor from being overshadowed by the forwarding-references constructor.

Comment: I suppose also universal reference for `args1` and `args2` in first contructor

Comment: What a shame:) Thanks!
Compiler errors weren't even close to pointing out, that the problem because of private using. Also, what seems interesting, this code causes clang to infinitely compile and eat all my RAM, although g++ compiles it without problems. And, if I add `enable_if`, clang will still be saying, that `Args1` is empty, as if there was no Id structure.

Comment: @NikitaVorobyev I removed your `contains` predicate, and in such a case it may lead to endless recursive calls, because forwarding references generate exact matches.

Comment: @max66 perfect forwarding in this case would require more effort, since `Args1` and `Args2` cannot be forwarding references (though it is possible to optimize this implementation, like e.g., forwarding the arguments as a tuple and extracting exact amount of elements for each constructor call)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, this was the question, I wanted to ask. How is it possible to perfectly forward Args?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki - You're right... it's more complicated. Nice update. Unfortunately I can't upvote (again) :(